# Why is it wrong to rank stocks by P/E ratio, sell the top quartile, and buy the bottom quartile?

Tags: backtesting, ratio

I am reading *Advances in Financial Machine Learning* by Marcos López de Prado. In chapter 11 *The Dangers of Backtesting*, exercise 11.5 asks:

> We download P/E ratios from Bloomberg, rank stocks every month, sell the top quartile, and buy the long quartile. Performance is amazing. What’s the sin?

Indeed, what is the problem? I don't see anything wrong with the method.

Comment: Beware of look ahead bias. The earnings of ACME Corp. for the second quarter of 2016 are not known on the last day of the second quarter of 2016. You need a database that has info about when the earnings were released and also when the earnings were amended/revised (if they were). Most db only have the latest info and the period to which it is related.

Comment: Also Bloomberg removes companies that have gone out of business. Another bias. You need a database that includes dead companies. In summmary Bloomberg is great for looking up the most recent info on current companies, it is not suited for historical backtests.

Comment: Small nitpick: it's hard to rank on P/E, since E can be zero or negative. Practically, it's easier to rank E/P. I think the sin is that you look at E now, ignoring future growth of E. Anyway, you may like http://people.stern.nyu.edu/adamodar/pdfiles/invfables/ch3new.pdf  and also https://doi.org/10.2307/2326304 S. Basu. Investment Performance of Common Stocks in Relation to Their Price-Earnings Ratios: A Test of the Efficient Market Hypothesis (1977).

Comment: @noob2 Your comments are helpful. Please copy them into an answer.

Comment: What is "performance"? You should not only look at raw returns but also compute risk-adjusted returns and various risk measures

Comment: The efficient markets hypothesis says that everything that Dr. López de Prado tries is useless :) because observable prices already include all the information known to anyone. E.g. a price might look low for the observed earnings because the market thinks that the future earnings are volatile/risky and won't grow. Conversely, a price might look high for the observed earnings because the market thinks that the future earnings are steady and will grow. You're looking for "wrong" prices in a world that has changed little ince Basu's 1977 paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proper backtesting is difficult, because of various biases that easily slip into the results if you are not careful.

For example how do you compute historical P/E's. Well, you have historical E's and historical P's so you can divide P by E (as Dimitri Vulis suggests it is better to divide E by P, as most academic studies do). However beware of look ahead bias (using information  in the backtest that was not available to investors at the time). The earnings of ACME Corp. for the year ending Q2 2016 are not known on the last day of the second quarter of 2016. They become public with a lag. You need a database that has info about when the earnings were released and also when the earnings were amended/revised (if they were). Most db only have the latest info and the period to which it is related. Instead you need "point in time" information, i.e. what information was available at various past points.

Also Bloomberg removes companies that have gone out of business. Another bias (survival bias, i.e. you are testing only the companies that survived). You need a database that includes dead companies.

In summmary Bloomberg is great for looking up the most recent info on current companies, it is not necessarily suited for historical backtests (at least without considerable additional work).

Comment: On Bloomberg‘s defence you can get both point-in-time index members as well as fundamentals :-)